# Displaying a view, with two filtered model related keys with django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm having trouble understanding the best approach to displaying a particular view

I have two models like this:

```
// models.py
class CarDealer(model.Models):
    name = model.TextField()
    slug = model.SlugField()

class Car(model.Models):
    name = model.TextField()
    color = model.TextField()
    dealer = model.ForeignKey('CarDealer', related_name'cars')
```

and the URL i'm trying to construct is:

```
// url.py
url(regex=r'^(?P<car_dealer_slug>[^/]*)/(?P<car_color_one>[^/]*)/(?P<car_color_two>[^/]*)/$',
    view=views.DealerCarColors.as_view(),
    name='dealer_car_colors')
```

So the url could be /dealer/blue/green and I want to display a list of dealers and a list of blue cars and green cars they have, or a list of no cars.

I want the view to display a table of:

```
|dealer | color 1| color 2|
---------------------------
|dealer1| car A  | car Z  |
|       | car B  | car X  |
|       | car C  |        |
---------------------------
|dealer2|        |        |
---------------------------
```

I'm trying to understand how do do this with class based views, that allow paging of the CarDealers, but is still able to display the two filtered lists of related objects.

I know this is possible in several ways, but what would be the most correct way? I.e. keeping all logic in the view.py file, rather than using filters.

Comment: Avoid creating such complicated urls, filter/search parameter should rather be in the GET data, like ?color=green&color=blue. And for me it does not make sense to show more than one dealer's car since /car_dealer_slug/ should be unique for only one dealer.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I can't edit my posts yet, but I wanted to remove the dealer in the URL.

Comment: Though even if the parameter's are in GET data, then there is still the same issue, of what is the best practice in constructing the model data.

Comment: @beluga.me I definitely agree with the first part (urls should be simpler), but regarding the second part of the comment: passing GET information through the URL using ?dealer=dealerName&color=green is for sure one way to do it, but I actually prefer /dealerName/colorName more because it is cleaner and more RESTful API like.

Comment: So what I'm actually trying to get is either /dealers/colorName1/ColorName2 or /dealers/?color=green&color=blue. Effectively I'm trying to understand how to construct a view where I can filter the items in a related model.

Answer (score 0):

You should really organize your URLs and think it through first. If a user wants to access cars of color green, then he'll go to

```
/dealer/green
```

and if he wants blue, he'll go to

```
/dealer/blue
```

If he wants cars colored green and cars colored blue, he'll go to each of the URLs above. Why would you want him to mix it in one URL when in the end, you're showing two separate lists of cars anyways? The view will look something like this:

```
class GetCars(APIView): # I'm using DRF so I'm extending a DRF view
    """
    List the cars based on the users filters.
    """

    def get(self, request, dealer, colorOne, colorTwo):
        cars = CarDealer.objects.filter(name=dealer, cars.color = colorOne) # Django code
        carsTwo = CarDealer.objects.filter(name=dealer, cars.color = colorTwo) # Django Code
        # then return both cars and carsTwo to the front-end
```

The code above uses DRF (I am using the APIView which is in DRF) but the only-Django view will use similar logic.

Edit: Also, your post says:

"So the url could be /dealer/blue/green and I want to display a list of dealers and a list of blue cars and green cars they have, or a list of no cars.

I want the view to display a table of:"

```
|dealer | color 1| color 2|
---------------------------
|dealer1| car A  | car Z  |
|       | car B  | car X  |
|       | car C  |        |
---------------------------
|dealer2|        |        |
---------------------------
```

You really shouldn't be displaying dealer2 if the user specifically went to the URL /dealer/color (because that implies he wants to see cars of that one specific dealer).

Edit: If you want multiple Car objects and not CarDealer objects, you can try:

```
    def get(self, request, dealer, colorOne, colorTwo):
        dealerObject = CarDealer.objects.get(name=dealer)
        cars = Car.objects.filter(dealer=dealerObject, color=colorOne)
```

Comment: This is question is less about the URL, but more about how to construct the view the django way. I couldn't edit the original question, but it's more like /dealers/?color=green&color=blue. With that, I want to see the data for each dealer, in the format of the table above.

Comment: @CodingMonkey Oh, sorry. I guess I interpreted "what would be the most correct way" incorrectly. Nonetheless, you'd probably end up using "cars = CarDealer.objects.filter(name=dealer, cars.color=colorOne)" in your view anyways, so I'll leave the answer posted until someone else has a better way.

Comment: I've tried filtering the query set like `qs = CarDealer.objects.filter(cars_color=colorOne)`, but that some how returns multiple CarDealer objects, one per result for cars_color.

Comment: @CodingMonkey If I understand you correct, you want multiple car objects, and not car dealer objects. See my edit at the bottom of the post of how you can do that. Basically, do "dealerObject = CarDealer.objects.get(name=dealer)" and then "cars = Car.objects.filter(dealer=dealerObject, color=colorOne)".